# Passing Jquery DataTables instance to onsubmit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a master details page, i have created a javascript function in an external file that is always called upon submitting any form, this function sends an ajax post call to the corresponding ASP.NET MVC controller, and upon success the controller returns a json object to the SubmitForm() function which in turn reloads the datatable instance and displays a notification, it has worked fine, but now that i need to display multiple datatables in the same page dynamically i always get an error (Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined)

I tried adding an optional parameter in the SubmitForm(form, id='') function, so in case my form returns an id, it reloads the corresponding datatable but it gave me that same error.

```
//JS function in file.js
function SubmitForm(form, id = '') {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
if ($(form).valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.action,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //global variable that is always present in all pages
                datatable.ajax.reload();
                if (id) {
                    var tbl = $(id).dataTable();
                    tbl.ajax.reload();
                }
                $(form)[0].reset();
                $.notify(data.message, { globalPosition: "top center", className: "success" });
                if (data.type != "Add") {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
return false;
}
  //MVC FORM in partial view
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEditSE", "ProjectStaff", FormMethod.Post, new 
{ id = "form", onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this,'#SE')" }))
{
    // elements
}
```

Expected result:

> Notify.js success message, and a reload of the corresponding datatable
>   (in this case #SE)

Actual Result:

> Error Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

Comment: You have provided a mix of client and server code; from this nobody can reproduce your error and resolve it for you. You need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Load your page up in a browser, cause the error and copy out the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem after some digging, i defined my datatable instant in a variable and in the form onsubmit property i sent that variable name, in the if statement i accessed the datatable API by using variablename.DataTable().ajax.reload();

```
function SubmitForm(form, tbl = null) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
if ($(form).valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.action,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                datatable.ajax.reload();
                if (tbl) {
                    //to access datatable instance, use varname.DataTable().
                    tbl.DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
                $(form)[0].reset();
                $.notify(data.message, { globalPosition: "top center", className: "success" });
                if (data.type != "Add") {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
return false;
}
```

Form partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEditSE", "ProjectStaff", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this,SETable)" }))
{
      // elements
}
```

index view

```
  var SETable;
  SETable = $("#SE").dataTable({ //parameters });
```